# Run another Local application in ASP.net website

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I run another Local Application (developed application using c#) through ASP.net website and will send parameters to the Local Application(such as Name,source file)?

(I understand that there will be security risk for this but I will consider suggestions) Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle your own URL-protocol like Skype does:

```
phone://123546
localapp://data
```

then create a link

```
<a href="localapp://data">Open App</a>
```

or try to redirect on the serverside

```
Response.Redirect("localapp://data");
```

[and handle it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

EXAMPLE:

Local Application (c:\localapp.exe):

```
using System;
class LocalApplication
{
  [STAThread]
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT 
     localapp
          (Default) = "URL:Local App"
          URL Protocol = ""
          shell
               open
                    command
                         (Default) = "c:\localapp.exe" "%1"
```

Html:

```
<a href="localapp://Hello">Start LocalApp</a>
```

Comment: We actually used it and it works like a charm.but it is limited to simple parameters

Comment: can you give me an example for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i've added a very basic example.if you google for "handle custom url-protocol" you might find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean start a local program on the server or on the client?

On the server you can [start a process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and pass it command line parameters for the information you need to access.

Comment: Not possible. Browser security restrictions.

Comment: @nunespascal - Eh...maybe an ActiveX control (are those even still around?)  Either way, this just sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I need to run a commenting tool program used for every PDF. This is like an author-proofing program that every articles will be check by its author.

Comment: @Tommy Nothing dies on the web. IE9 still supports them, although you have to explicitly enable them for websites.

Comment: @nunespascal - Valid point.  I have never used them, so wasn't sure if they were even still around :)

Comment: Could you use a click once target? That will give the appearance that the application is being "launched" from the website

Comment: How can I use "click once target"? and will launch the said program?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible due to security restrictions on most modern browsers.

If you can restrict your users to IE(very bad practice), ActiveX controls could do that. Here is a small code snippet.

```
<SCRIPT Language="JScript">
function runcmd() {
File="cmd.exe";
WSH=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WSH.run(File);
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Yes. I know this but I think I can't restrict them.